# File access error not thrown from Linux App-1(C#) even if File is currently be written by another Linux App-2(C++)

Tags: c#, linux

I am facing a weird issue in our C# .NET Core applications running on Linux (ubuntu) server.
We have 2 Apps running. App1 starts creating a file and writing into it. App2 then tries to access the file but doesn't raise any file exception.

App1 C++ code:

```
char m_filePath[1024] = "/home/ubuntu/src/Test/123.txt"; 
mode_t perms = S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH;
const char buf[512] = "123";
int fd = open(m_filePath, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_SYNC |O_EXCL, perms);
if (fd >= 0) 
{
  std::cout<<"Wav file : {} Created successfully "<<std::endl;
} 
while(1)         
{                 
   write(fd,&buf, 1);
}
```

App2 C# code:

```
                 var mediaFilePath = @"/home/ubuntu/src/Test/123.txt";
                if (File.Exists(mediaFilePath))
                {
                    var fs = File.OpenWrite(mediaFilePath);
                    fs.Close();
                    fs.Dispose();                        
                    Console.WriteLine("File FREE TO ACCESs");
                }
```

File.OpenWrite() does not throw any IO exception and App2 is able to access the File without any problem :(

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What do the docs say `CanWrite` means? Since it doesn't do what you _think_ it does.

Comment: Try fs.Flush() before closing the stream.

Comment: I have updated my question, I have used File.OpenWrite() which is throwing exception when I created a file and writing from a C# test app. But when the same file is created from a C++ test app and writing into it, File.OpenWrite() did not throw any exception. Not sure why ..